# Calculate Estimated Gas Price In Eth using ethers.js

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I am using ethers.js to transfer eth between wallets. I want to show the user the estimated transaction fee (in ETH) in my UI before the user sends the eth. So currently i use

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('rpc_url');
const {
gasPrice, maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas
} = await provider.getFeeData();
```

I get the gasPrice, maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas. How do I use these values to calculate the actual estimated transaction fee to be paid by the user in ETH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot calculate the total fee just by these values.

The total fee is calculated as "units of gas used * (base fee + priority fee)"

"units of gas used" equals 21,000 units (expected gas usage for sending ETH)

"priority fee" is represented by maxPriorityFeePerGas value

"base fee" is undefined, because JSON RPC doesn't provide a method that returns the base fee.

The base fee is calculated independently for each block.
You can use something like [Blocknative Gas Platform API](https://docs.blocknative.com/gas-platform) to get the probabilistic value of the base fee.